# Kundera with cassandra1.1.9 and play framework2.0.4

Tags: playframework-2.0, cassandra, kundera

I tried the kundera cassandra over java play framework 2.0.4 example on [https://github.com/firekat/play-kundera] (https://github.com/firekat/play-kundera). 
 I got exception.. exception stack trace
`2013-02-03 22:56:35,201 - [ERROR] - from com.impetus.kundera.persistence.PersistenceValidator in play-akka.actor.actions-dispatcher-9 
class models.User is not a JPA managed object as we couldn't find metadata for it. This object can't be persisted
2013-02-03 22:56:35,230 - [ERROR] - from application in play-akka.actor.actions-dispatcher-9 
! @6d86e1m37 - Internal server error, for request [GET /user/create/:Emin] ->`

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[KunderaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity object is invalid, operation failed. Please check previous log message for details]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:516) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity object is invalid, operation failed. Please check previous log message for details
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:220) ~[kundera-core-2.3.jar:na]
    at controllers.KunderaApp.createUser(KunderaApp.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(routes_routing.scala:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$5$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:1090) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:33) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:19) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:17) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:104) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:14) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$class.apply(JavaAction.scala:74) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$5$$anon$1.apply(Router.scala:1089) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Invoker.scala:126) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anonfun$6.apply(Invoker.scala:126) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:17) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:125) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity object is invalid, operation failed. Please check previous log message for details
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.PersistenceDelegator.persist(PersistenceDelegator.java:146) ~[kundera-core-2.3.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:214) ~[kundera-core-2.3.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
 You may think that I created my keyspace and column family. This is what I did in cassandra -cli and I checked it is working and I could ınsert data via -cli
[screenshoot http://c1302.hizliresim.com/16/3/jqzdp.png](http://c1302.hizliresim.com/16/3/jqzdp.png)

Answer (score 1):

As per error:

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Duplicate persistence-units for name: cassandra_pu. verify your persistence.xml file]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:82) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:63) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:290) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:61) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:617) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:179) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:161) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:505) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:997) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1495) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) [akka-actor.jar:2.0]
**Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Duplicate persistence-units for name: cassandra_pu. verify your persistence.xml file**
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:103) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:64) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:103) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:81) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]

===================================
I suggest you to change persistence unit name under (META-INF/persistence.xml) and try running it.

-Vivek

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I moved the issue with detail on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/kundera-discuss/vIyoaPCF5Vo